# Pass a variable from a running process to another process (alfresco - activiti)

Tags: java, process, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Greetings to the community, I am using Alfresco 6.0.0 (Community Edition) and I am wondering if the following scenario would be possibly achieved.

**Step 1**

Start a process through the alfresco workflow console with *definition = 'process1'*

**Step 2**

Start a second process through the alfresco workflow console with *definition = 'process2'*

I wonder if I somehow could "interact" with the *process1* from *process2*

(for example, **update a variable that exists in the process1 from process2**)

In case the above scenario is feasible, I would prefer to do that either inside the .bpmn file of my *process2* or maybe using a **serviceTask** extending a custom **JavaDelegate** method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, process instances should be isolated. but for your case, you can create a JAVA Bean (singleton) that holds the values and inject that bean wherever required. just make sure it initializes in the engine context. update the bean with one process and use the bean instance values using activiti expression i.e `${myBean.getVaue("yourVariable")}`

your bean definition should look like -

```
@Component("myBean")
public class MyBean {

    // your variables

    public Object getVaue(String variableName) {
        // return your variable value
    }
}
```

Note: keep your variables thread safe